# WCF client configuration for 3rd party SOAP 1.1 service with plain text username credentials over SSL

Tags: wcf, soap, wcf-security, ws-security, basichttpbinding

I am trying to connect to a third party SOAP 1.1 service that requires SSL security and username/password credentials. An example of what is expected is:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsse:Security>
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password>password</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

My client configuration is as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="thirdpartyservicebindingconfig">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName"
                             algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://..." 
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="thirdpartyservicebindingconfig"
                  contract="thirdpartyservicecontract" 
                  name="thirdpartyserviceendpoint" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Service client code is:

```
var client = new thirdpartyservicecontractclient();

client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

var result = client.DoSomething();
```

I'm getting the following fault exception message:

> Security processor was unable to find a security header in the
>   message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or
>   because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating
>   parties. This can occur if the service is configured for security and
>   the client is not using security..

**EDIT:**
If I reconfigure security mode to "Transport": 
`<security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">`
I get an error from the third party service:

> com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Message does not conform to
>   configured policy [ AuthenticationTokenPolicy(S) ]:  No Security
>   Header found; nested exception is
>   com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException:
>   com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Message does not conform to
>   configured policy [ AuthenticationTokenPolicy(S) ]:  No Security
>   Header found.

How can I configure my client to connect to this service?

- WS Security using plain text passwords over SSL

Comment: I don't have the answer I'm afraid, but think you're on the right lines with TransportWithMessageCredential (i.e. the user / pass is in the SOAP header, then the entire thing is passed over an encrypted SSL connection), and basicHttpBinding which I believe is SOAP 1.1

Comment: Are the 3rd party able to share a working client config with you?  Or is the 3rd party a non-WCF implementation that you're now using WCF to connect to?

Comment: @KrisC. The 3rd party service in build in Java.

Comment: Does this help at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9913662/issues-with-wcf-and-soap-ws-security-plaintext-username-no-ssl

Comment: @Kris - I'm afraid it doesn't. I've spent all day researching this and I've found the [solution](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/09/Tracing-WCF-Messages). Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm likely to have to configure something fairly similar in the not too distant future.  Thanks for sharing the solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It just so happens Rick Strahl had the same problem. [Here's the link](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/09/Tracing-WCF-Messages) to his blog post describing and solving the problem.

Issue:

> The issue is that WCF expects a TimeStamp Soap header in the response.
>   If you look at the outbound response and the Soap headers you'll see
>   that there's a timestamp there. The timestamp is expected to be
>   returned on the return Soap response.  Note that this is not a
>   requirement of WS-Security so WCF is doing something 'special' here
>   that is in effect breaking this service call.

Solution:

```
BindingElementCollection elements = client.Endpoint.Binding.CreateBindingElements();
elements.Find<SecurityBindingElement>().IncludeTimestamp = false;
client.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements);
```

> The above code modifies the Binding configuration by explicitly
>   removing the Timestamp from the outbound call which removes the
>   requirement for the server to return it. And this makes WCF happy and
>   the call goes through.