# .NET WCF client and Java SOAP service error

Tags: java, .net, wcf, soap

I'm using .NET WCF client to connect to SOAP service (implemented on Java). Client certificate authentication is used. Here is the binding configuration code:

```
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding
{
    Security = new BasicHttpSecurity
    {
        Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential,
        Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity
        {
            ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate
        }
    }
};
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("https://[service_url]"));

var service = new ServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(
    StoreLocation.LocalMachine, StoreName.My,
    X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "certificate_thumbprint");
```

Here is the error that Java server side returns when trying to connect using the configuration:

> com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Message does not conform to
>   configured policy (found Signature) : Additional security than
>   required found

What is the problem here?

Comment: Looks like there is a configuration difference between your `Java` service and your `WCF` client.. Could you add more detail as to the security configuration of your service and the client?

Comment: In order to get meaningful feedback, you most likely will need to include details about the web service definition (wsdl) and/or the underlying policies

Comment: I suspect there is a mandatory/required entry in the calls. Please post the wsdl for further review.

Comment: I do not think it has anything to do with the wsdl. Try to use tcpmon to find the differences between the message sent by a wcf client and the message sent by a java client. You can use SoapUI as a java client.

Comment: Hope this can help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026768/wcf-client-configuration-for-3rd-party-soap-1-1-service-with-plain-text-username